# How to remove folder where the executable is

Tags: c++, directory, uninstallation

I created a simple uninstall routine, made some external bat in temp folder, which is started from application, the bat deletes all files from directory (where application is installed). Now I have problem when all files are deleted from folder (including application by itself), I can not delete folder.

Here is code for bat

```
ofstream batch;
batch.open(TempPath.c_str(), ios::out);
batch << "timeout 2" << "\n";
batch << "RD /S /Q \"C:\\Program Files\\Application\" /q\n";
batch << "timeout 5" << "\n";
batch << "rmdir \"C:\\Program Files\\Application\"";
batch.close();
```

Now the question is how to remove folder after deleting all files from it?

Comment: Is there an error you receive when you try to delete the folder? Permission issue? In use?

Comment: when i try from cmd it say access denied

Comment: Interesting, but I think difficult. You would need to copy an uninstaller EXE to a temp directory and run it. Depending on where your application is installed, you would probably need to run it with Administrative privileges. Why are you rolling your own installer/uninstaller? WIX is free and useful. http://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: Are you using the wrong tags? This looks to be C++, not C#?

Comment: @RonBeyer -> have some special requirement for installer and uninstaller, that is why i dont use some other setups

Comment: @yes it c++ but idea is same

Comment: You should be using rmdir with the /s option. And the batch file needs to run under administrative privileges to modify the program files directory. If you tag it correctly you get much higher quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
batch << "RD /S /Q \"C:\\Program Files\\Application\" /s /q\n";
```

> /s   : Removes the specified directory and all subdirectories
>   including any files. Use /s to remove a tree.

Also make sure that the batch script has admin premissions, otherwise the OS will deny it changing files that are located in `C:\Program Files\`